# extracting numbers from vector of text

Tags: r, regex, string

How would you extract the numbers from the "text" column so that you can create the "outcome" column below?

```
dat = data.frame (text = c("int[1]","int[2]","int[3]","int[11]","be[4]","be[30]"),
outcome = c(1,2,3,11,4,30))



     text outcome
1  int[1]       1
2  int[2]       2
3  int[3]       3
4 int[11]      11
5   be[4]       4
6  be[30]      30
```

Comment: Can you just pull all numbers between the `[]`? `dat$outcome <- gsub("(^.+\\[)(\\d+)(\\]$)", "\\2", dat$text)`.

Comment: `as.integer(gsub("[^0-9]", "", dat$text))`? This is naïve and simple, no pos/neg, no decimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My commented solution is naïve solution:

```
as.integer(gsub("[^0-9]", "", dat$text))
```

(This is effectively identical to Santosh's answer, which instead uses a character class of `\\D` to denote "anything except a digit".) It works as long as there are not two or more groups of numbers, for instance, `"5a4"`will return `54`, not what you might expect. ycw's answer is somewhat better in that it find the first contiguous group of numbers, so it would return `5` there. Imperfect.

D.sen's comment was a bit more resilient in that, *if you are confident that the numbers are always within brackets*, then it will not be distracted by leading or following numbers.

```
gsub("(^.+\\[)(\\d+)(\\]$)", "\\2", dat$text)
```

I might suggest extending the third regex group a little, as `(\\].*$)"`, since that will still match if/when there are characters after the right bracket. Then again, if you are confident that this "should never happen", then perhaps you want to know (with a functional failure) when that pattern fails.

All this assumes positive integers. You can extend mine with `[0-9.]` and D.sen's by replacing `\\d` with `[0-9.]` (since I don't know of a character class off-hand that includes the decimal). Neither approach offers negative numbers, exponentiation, or whatever; there are plenty of regex guides out there that will provide more robust methods for catching all of a "non-trivial number".

Answer (score 1):

```
dat$outcome <- as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", dat$text))
dat

     text  outcome
1  int[1]       1
2  int[2]       2
3  int[3]       3
4 int[11]      11
5   be[4]       4
6  be[30]      30
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `stringr`.

```
# Create example data frame
dat <- data.frame(text = c("int[1]","int[2]","int[3]","int[11]","be[4]","be[30]"))

library(stringr)
# Use str_extract
dat$outcome <- as.numeric(str_extract(dat$text, "[0-9]+"))
dat
     text outcome
1  int[1]       1
2  int[2]       2
3  int[3]       3
4 int[11]      11
5   be[4]       4
6  be[30]      30
```